# How to set empty value to DateTimeField WebControl?

Tags: 2010, date-time

We tried to use `DateTime.MaxValue` to set empty value for DateTimeField and it works quite nice on our test environment, but we get following exception on some production farms.

> Exception: Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and
>   DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks. Parameter name: ticks, Stack Trace: at
>   System.DateTime..ctor(Int64 ticks) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTimeZone.ConvertToUTC(DateTime date, UInt16
>   tzid) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DateTimeField.set_Value(Object value)

Can anyone suggest how we can workaround this?

Answer (score 2):

try handling it with `IsDateEmpty` property, while saving it. for e.g.

```
if (!yourDatecontrol.IsDateEmpty)
{
    item["Date"] = yourDatecontrol.SelectedDate;
}
else
{
    item["Date"] = null;
}
```

Call ClearSelection method for empty value.

```
yourDatecontrol.ClearSelection();
```